# Custom tag object as input property in angular

Tags: angular, object, input

i work on an intranet so i can't show my code here but i will try to do my best to reproduce the main pieces of code to help show what i am looking to achieve.

i inherited code that is something like this...

```
export class OurComponent {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;

    constructor(data: any) {
        this.prop1 = data.prop1;
        this.prop2 = data.prop2;
    }
}

export class OurComponent1 implements OurComponent {

    someProp: string;

    constructor(data: any) {
        super(data);
        this.someProp = data.someProp;
    }
}

export class OurComponent2 implements OurComponent {
    someOtherProp: string;
    constructor(data: any){
        super(data);
        this.someOtherProp = data.someOtherProp;
    }
}

 
    

@Component({
    selector: 'our-custom-component'
    ...
})
export class OurCustomComponent {
    @Input() field: OurComponent;
    @Input() yetAnotherProp: number;
}






<!-- display of our-custom-component in a random template -->
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let loopValue of loopValues">

        <div *ngIf="loopValue.typeToShow === 'ourComponent1'">
            <our-custom-component
                [field]="{prop1: v1, prop2: v2, someProp: v3}"
                yetAnotherProp="1"
            >
            </our-component>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="loopValue.typeToShow === 'ourComponent2'">
            <our-custom-component
                [field]="{prop1: v1, prop2: v2, someOtherProp: v3}"
                yetAnotherProp="2"
            >
            </our-component>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

the code (mostly) works as we'd like and appears to figure out which implementation of OurComponent to create.

a couple of things of note...

1. if i put a breakpoint in the constructor of OurComponent, OurComponent1 or OurComponent2 it never breaks in there.
2. is there a way to cast the object passed into the custom tag input? i was hoping that would force the breakpoint to work in the constructor.

it would be nice if we could do something like this, but it doesn't work...

```
  <our-component
      [field]="new OurComponent2({prop1: v1, prop2: v2, someOtherProp: v3})"
      yetAnotherProp="2"
   >
   </our-component>
```

anyone have comments/suggestions for the 2 items of note?

Comment: You could move the `typeToShow === 'ourComponent1'` from your html a typescript method and pass the result of that method as input for your `[field]`, there you could use the constructors of your classes.

Answer (score 0):

Fussel was on the right track. here is what i ended up doing...

component...

```
    componentMap: Map<string, OurComponent> = new Map();
    
    getOrCreateOurComponent1(initData: any) {
        const comp1 = componentMap.get('comp1');
        if (!comp1) {
            comp1 = new OurComponent1(initData);
            componentMap.set('comp1', comp1);
        }
        return comp1;
    }

// similar method for component 2 here
```

html...

```
<!-- display of our-custom-component in a random template -->

    <div>
        <div *ngFor="let loopValue of loopValues">
    
            <div *ngIf="loopValue.typeToShow === 'ourComponent1'">
                <our-custom-component
                    [field]="getOrCreateOurComponent1({prop1: v1, prop2: v2, someProp: v3})"
                    yetAnotherProp="1"
                >
                </our-component>
            </div>
    
            <div *ngIf="loopValue.typeToShow === 'ourComponent2'">
                <our-custom-component
                    [field]="getOrCreateOurComponent2{prop1: v1, prop2: v2, someOtherProp: v3})"
                    yetAnotherProp="2"
                >
                </our-component>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    </div>
```

the reason i had to put the objects in a Map is because at first i simply returned a new object and i was still having the same problem i was trying to solve which is the custom dropdown in OurComponent1 was not allowing an item to be selected. when i put a breakpoint in the getComponent1() function (original name i gave to getOrCreateComponent1()) i noticed it was breaking there many times therefore creating many instances. so, as soon as i made it getOrCreateComponent1() and made sure only one instance of our custom component was used then everything worked. the dropdown in our component worked. before the dropdown displayed and even the correct value displayed but couldn't select anything.

It is strange because other custom components we created have radio inputs in them and they don't have any strange side effects without having to make sure only one instance of each is created. seems like only the custom dropdown we made had a problem with multiple instances. i'm not sure why that is.